# Regress y on x and vice versa

Tags: r, regression

I want to do a regression of x on y instead of y on x. Can I easily exchange y and x to do so? To clearify: I would change `lm(Y ~ X, data =...)` to `lm(X ~ Y, data =...)`.

I'm a bit concerned if I then have to modify for example Pearson residuals to estimate the goodness of fit somehow. Or is this automatically considered in `R` ?

And in general: How do I choose to regress which one on which: Just simple when I'm interested in y then I regress y on x and vice versa?

Comment: Typically from chronology (or causality), if x comes first, then x is independent and y is dependent variable: y = f(x). With linear relation you would write in R formula y ~ x.

Comment: Thanks! So when x is independent I would regress y on x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That regress Y on X can be typically thought as an abbreviation from a mathematically more accurate task:

Find a surface parametrized by X such that when values of Y are *projected on* the surface, the sum of squared distances of Y from the surface X measured along the projections get minimized. Thus, regress Y *on* X

```
fit <- lm(Y ~ X, data = ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the background explanation! Probably I seem a bit dumb but is the plain application to change a regression of y on x just exchanging these two parameters? fit<- lm(X ~ Y, data=...)?

Comment: On right hand side of the formala you may typically have even a more complicated expression: `lm(X ~ Y + Z + ..., data=...)`, so that X is projected on the surface parametrized by several attributes `Y`, `Z`, etc. Depending on the context, switching X and Y, an explanatory variable and the target, does or does not make sense.

Comment: Ah, ok. But in case of only two variables this would be sufficient?

Comment: Of course, if you have only X and Y, formula `Y ~ X` is enough for linear regression.